# Dit-on « sur une île » ou « dans une île » ?

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

Dans le dictionnaire j'ai trouvé qu'il faut employer *dans*.

En revanche, j'ai trouvé plusieurs exemples qui disent « sur une île ».

Y a-t-il une règle grammaticale qui peut m'expliquer la différence entre les deux ?

Answer (score 10):

On disait plus « dans une île » mais la tendance à commencé à s'inverser à partir des années 50 et « sur une île » est plus utilisé depuis 1990 (« sur une île déserte » depuis 1970).

cf [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dans%20une%20%C3%AEle%2Csur%20une%20%C3%AEle%2Csur%20une%20%C3%AEle%20d%C3%A9serte%2Cdans%20une%20%C3%AEle%20d%C3%A9serte&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdans%20une%20%C3%AEle%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdans%20une%20%C3%AEle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDans%20une%20%C3%AEle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csur%20une%20%C3%AEle%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsur%20une%20%C3%AEle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSur%20une%20%C3%AEle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csur%20une%20%C3%AEle%20d%C3%A9serte%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsur%20une%20%C3%AEle%20d%C3%A9serte%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSur%20une%20%C3%AEle%20d%C3%A9serte%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cdans%20une%20%C3%AEle%20d%C3%A9serte%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdans%20une%20%C3%AEle%20d%C3%A9serte%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDans%20une%20%C3%AEle%20d%C3%A9serte%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

La démocratisation des voyages en avion a peut-être rendu les îles moins isolées et plus « plates », comme semble le montrer la corrélation remarquable avec la recherche « agence de voyage ».

[image]

[image]

On peut aussi remarquer que « dans » et « sur » ne sont pas toujours interchangeables lorsqu'ils s'appliquent à une île.

Si, par exemple, on se trouve déjà sur une île mais sur la côte et que l'on va visiter l'intérieur de l'île, on dira bien plus naturellement « je vais dans l'île » que « je vais sur l'île ».

Comment: Il manque [celui-là](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dans+l%27%C3%AEle%2Csur+l%27%C3%AEle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdans%20l%27%20%C3%AEle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csur%20l%27%20%C3%AEle%3B%2Cc0), qui étonnamment donne le résultat inverse, tout comme "dans cette île" vs "sur cette île" par exemple.

Comment: @MorganFR Ces graphiques ne donnent pas un résultat inverse. La tendance est similaire (baisse de « dans » et augmentation de « sur »)  mais « sur » part ici de plus bas. « Sur l'île » dépasse dans « dans l'île » en 2005 alors qu'il était 5 fois moins fréquent en 1950, « sur cette île » a rattrapé plus des deux tiers de son retard sur la même période.

Comment: Bien entendu, la tendance est vers le bas, mais à ce jour, pour certaines expressions, "dans" est toujours plus utilisé alors pour d'autres, "sur" est plus répandu (j'utilise plutôt "sur" également).

Comment: @MorganFR Oui, je comprends. Ce que je veux dire, c'est que ma réponse montrait déjà que suivant les expressions, « sur » rattrapait « dans » à des dates différentes (1970 et 1990). Les expressions « sur l'île » et « dans l'île » suivent la même tendance, les résultats ne sont donc pas « étonnamment inverses » mais au contraire confirment la même tendance.

Answer (score 3):

Les deux sont corrects, à ma connaissance, mais partagent deux idées différentes :

- Dans une île > Une idée d'espace fermé se crée.
- Sur une île > Une idée de surface se crée. C'est ce que j'utilise le plus souvent. Je trouve que ça ajoute au côté « terre sur la mer. »

Généralement j'entends plus souvent le second cas, mais les deux sont corrects.