# Dans la lune ou sur la lune

Tags: prépositions

Pendant qu'on regardait un épisode de « The Crown » dont l'action se déroule au milieu du programme Apollo, on a discuté chez nous du choix entre « dans la lune » et « sur la lune ».

Une recherche sur Ngrams montre que c'est à cette époque-là que « sur la lune » l'a emporté une fois pour toutes !

[image: ngram sur la lune vs dans la lune]

Est-ce que ces deux expressions étaient interchangeables avant ce moment ? Le sont-elles aujourd'hui ? Est-ce dû à l'emprunt aux publications anglaises qu'on a opté si vigoureusement pour « sur la lune » ("on the moon") ? Est-ce qu'on réserve « sur la lune » pour des voyages spatiaux ?

Il y a quand même le fameux Voyage dans la lune ...

Comment: Pour moi `être dans la lune` signifie `avoir la tête ailleurs`, `être perdu dans ses pensées` et rien d'autre. Je serais bien étonné d'une autre utilisation de `dans la lune`.

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23178/dit-on-sur-une-%c3%aele-ou-dans-une-%c3%aele/23182#23182

Answer (score 4):

Ces deux expressions n'ont pas du tout le même sens!

Sur la lune = Alunir avec un engin spatial par exemple. Se trouver sur la surface lunaire.

Dans la lune = être dans la lune, ne pas être mentalement présent, ni "les pieds sur terre".

On ne peut pas dire "dans la lune" en parlant d'un engin spatial qui alunit,
"Dans" n'a pas le sens d'être sur la surface de la planète, mais "à l'intérieur", c'est réservé à un usage poétique. Pierrot est dans la lune, pas sur la lune, on voit sa frimousse quand on observe l'astre.

On dit "sur Mars", pas "dans Mars", pour cette même raison, il n'y a pas d'usage poétique pour Mars.

Le *voyage dans la lune* est utilisé pour les œuvres de fictions, en raison du caractère poétique. (C'était peut-être aussi comme cela qu'on en parlait autrefois y compris d'une manière scientifique, mais ce n'est plus le cas aujourd'hui.)

Il suffit de taper sur Google "Voyage dans la lune", et "Voyage sur la lune", et de regarder les articles et les images, pour finir de se convaincre de la différence d'emplois.

Comment: Concernant le titre du film de Méliès: les "astronautes" explorent bien les profondeurs de la Lune, cela peut aussi expliquer l'utilisation de "dans". Même chose pour le roman de HG Wells "Les premiers hommes dans la lune". Peut-être les artistes de cette époque partageaient-ils la même vision d'un objet stellaire creux, aux secrets cachés sous sa surface ?

Comment: ça confirme ce que j'en disais: c'est un usage poétique. Il suffit de voir le film de Méliès pour s'en persuader (avec la lune qui ferme un œil). Pour l'usage ancien, il est bien possible (comme je le disais + haut) qu'on ait utilisé "dans" même avec une idée de "science" en tête, mais on ne savait que peu de choses de l'apparence de la lune. Usage "scientifique" (ou pseudo) et poétique étaient mêlés.

Answer (score 0):

En des temps assez lointains on disait « dans la lune » pour exprimer « sur la lune » comme par exemple dans « *Le monde dans la lune* »  de John Wilkins - 1656 
([books](https://books.google.fr))

ou encore dans « *Les Femmes Savantes* »  de Molière (1622-1673) ([littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/lune)).

- Vous devriez… Ne point aller chercher ce qu'on fait dans la lune, Et vous mêler un peu de ce qu'on fait chez vous, Molière, Femm. sav. II, 7. Il me tarde… de nous signaler par quelque découverte… Pour moi, sans me flatter, j'en ai déjà fait une, Et j'ai vu clairement des hommes dans la lune, Molière, ib. III, 2.

Au [siècle des lumières](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Si%C3%A8cle_des_Lumi%C3%A8res) (mouvement littéraire et culturel que connaît l'Europe du XVIIIe siècle (de 1715 à 1789), c'est à dire environ un siècle plus tard, possiblement sous l'influence du sens de « de la lune » ([réf.](https://www.edilivre.com/expression-de-la-semaine/)), laquelle locution qualifie  un rêveur, « dans la lune », commence à signifier « distrait, inattentif, perdu dans ses pensées » ([Ac](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/lune?page=1)).

Donc, « dans la lune », qui a toujours été plus utilisé que « sur la lune » et le restera jusqu'aux évènements marquants dont il est fait mention dans la question originelle va commencer à être aussi utilisé pour un autre sens que le sens premier et c'est un sens qui prendra le dessus, à tel point que de nos jours c'est essentiellement de ce dernier sens dont il est question lorsque l'on dit « dans la lune ». Néanmoins, le sens premier n'est pas éteint. On relève ce sens dans plus de vingt parutions récentes, beaucoup dans les titres de livres, dans des titres de manifestations culturelles diverses et même dans des articles de vulgarisation scientifiques, si toutefois peu dans le texte. On remarque que pour le TLFi et le dictionnaire de l'Académie, de nos jours le sens premier n'existe pas ([ngram](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lune), [ngram](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/lune?page=1)), ce qui n'est pas une indication comme on n'y trouve pas non plus « dans les étoiles » alors que  « aller dans les étoiles » et « voyager dans les étoiles » sont des locutions utilisées.

Il est clair qu'un changement à pris place et que « sur la lune » est la forme préférée, ce qui rétablit dans le cas de la lune l'usage tout à fait logique que l'on trouve dans « sur la Terre » ou « sur Mars ».

« Atterrir dans la lune », et « atterri dans la lune » ne se disent pas ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=atterrir+dans+la+lune&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=), [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=atterri+dans++la+lune&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)) alors que « atterrir sur la lune » est courant depuis à peu près 1960 ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=atterrir+sur+la+lune&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Catterrir%20sur%20la%20lune%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Catterrir%20sur%20la%20lune%3B%2Cc0), exactement le début de la période lorsque l'on a commencé à parler du projet américain Apollo. Il n'existe aucune spécialisation de la préposition aux voyage spatiaux mais dans son usage en ce qui concerne les corps célestes une utilisation selon les possibilités habituelles dans lesquelles une opposition est établie entre « intérieur » (dans) et la frontière de l'intérieur (coté externe) (dessus, essentiellement).

- Sur la lune il y a des montagnes. — Marcher sur la lune est amusant pendant un moment, mais pas plus. — Il faut faire pousser des laitues sur la lune. — Sur la lune l'énergie solaire est une solution idéale. — Sur la lune il n'y aura peut-être pas de minerai très utile à la civilisation.

---

#### *Des occurrences récentes de « dans la lune » dans son sens premier*

Les voyages dans la lune - Page 7
https://books.google.fr › books
Jules Verne, ‎Edgar Allan Poe, ‎Francis Godwin - 2014 - ‎Aperçu - ‎Autres éditions
Les voyages dans la lune » est une compilation de romans qui ont en commun les voyages vers et sur la lune. Mêlant à la fois le picaresque, l'utopique, la satire, la parodie, le divertissement, l'initiatique et annonçant parfois la sciencefiction, ...

Une Mission Internationale Dans La Lune
https://books.google.fr › books
Jean Petithuguenin - 2016 - ‎Aucun aperçu - ‎Autres éditions
Une équipe internationale de 11 personnes embarquent à bord du «Selenit», un vaisseau spatial construit à Philadelphie, qui les mènera dans l'espage pour explorer la Lune avant de tenter de retourner sur Terre...

Voyage dans la lune: L ́autre monde ou Les états et empires ...
https://books.google.fr › books
Savinien Cyrano de Bergerac - 1987 - ‎Aucun aperçu

En moins d'une, dans la lune
https://books.google.fr › books
Christophe Alline, ‎Michel Piquemal - 1999 - ‎Aucun aperçu
Attention, on va démarrer ! Montez vite dans la fusée en route pour la voie lactée...

Moi j'irai dans la lune: et autres innocentines
https://books.google.fr › books
René de Obaldia - 1998 - ‎Aucun aperçu - ‎Autres éditions
Des textes très rythmés, poétiques et grinçants, qui racontent avec humour les choses et les rêves de la vie : un départ en "ouiquenne", "you spique angliche ?", "le secret", "moi j'irai dans la lune", "le zizi perpétuel"... seize ...

Dans la lune
https://books.google.fr › books
Eléonore Cannone - 2011 - ‎Aucun aperçu
L’histoire de Lucas qui, pour son huitième anniversaire a droit à un voyage dans l’espace… Un récit futuriste spécialement écrit pour les grands, pour faire découvrir à son enfant le plaisir de lire tout seul.

Le Voyage dans la Lune | littlekmbo
https://www.littlekmbo.com › le-voyage-dans-la-lune
LE VOYAGE DANS LA LUNE. au cinéma le 6 novembre 2019. Un film de Rasmus A. Siversten - 80 minutes - DCP - VF - n° de visa : 151529. À partir de 5 ans.

Des enfants dans la lune, c'est le propre de la fête de la ...
https://www.lavoixdunord.fr › Région › Arrageois - Ternois
6 oct. 2019 - Il y a eu du monde dès le matin dans les allées et dans les jardins de Cité Nature, à Arras, pour cette nouvelle édition de la fête de la science.

Le Voyage Dans La Lune - Opera Comique à Paris | Billets ...
https://www.fnacspectacles.com › fr-fr › place-spectacle › ticket-evenement
Achetez vos places pour Le Voyage Dans La Lune du 25/05/2020 au 31/05/2020 au meilleur prix sur Fnac Spectacles, leader de la billetterie en France. Retrait ...

« Dans la Lune » - Festival Big Bang - Saint-Médard-en-Jalles
www.festival-bigbang.com › programme › dans-la-lune-de-fanette-mellier
L'exposition montre un cycle lunaire géant en sérigraphie, dans lequel chaque lune est sur-imprimée à la lune précédente.

Les Premiers hommes dans la lune - Folio - Folio ... - Gallimard
www.gallimard.fr › Catalogue › Folio › Les-Premiers-hommes-dans-la-lune
288 pages, sous couverture illustrée, 108 x 178 mm. Achevé d'imprimer : 10-04-1984. Genre : Romans et récits Catégorie > Sous-catégorie : Littérature ...

UN LUTIN DANS LA LUNE | Culture Sud Toulousain
www.culturesudtoulousain.fr › agenda › un-lutin-dans-la-lune
Cie Lézards de la scène. La lune est si belle ! Elle brille comme une bulle de paillettes ! Mon petit lutin voudrait bien y aller… Partir sur la lune ! C'est possible ?

Moi j'irai dans la lune et autres innocentines, de René de ...
https://www.grasset.fr › livres › moi-jirai-dans-la-lune-et-autres-innocentin...
Voici une édition merveilleusement illustrée par Emmanuelle Houdart des célèbres "poèmes pour enfants et quelques adultes" de René de Obaldia ! Des textes ...

Il y a 50 ans, souvenirs de Réunionnais dans la Lune ...
https://la1ere.francetvinfo.fr › réunion
15 juil. 2019 - Le monde entier commémorera le 50ème anniversaire des premiers pas de l'Homme sur la Lune ce dimanche 21 juillet. Plusieurs ...

Concours d'écriture collégiens "Moi, j'irai dans la Lune ...
https://lenord.fr › concours-d-ecriture-collegiens-moi-j-irai-dans-la-lune
7 janv. 2019 - La villa Marguerite-Yourcenar lance la nouvelle édition de son concours d'écriture destiné aux collégiens du Nord en partenariat avec le ...

Hop, dans la Lune ! | Didier Jeunesse
https://didier-jeunesse.com › collections › hop-dans-la-lune-9782278081561
30 mars 2016 - Lala la petite chienne rêve de rencontrer les trois petits lapins qui se cachent sur la Lune. Ni une, ni deux, elle embarque avec la petite souris à ...

Premiers hommes dans la lune (Les) | l'école des loisirs
https://www.ecoledesloisirs.fr › livre › premiers-hommes-lune
Le savant Cavor et l'aventurier Bedford, ayant accompli l'exploit de se poser sur la Lune grâce à la cavorite, un matériau qui les libère des lois de la gravité, ...

Voyage dans la Lune | L'Onde Théâtre - Centre d'art
https://www.londe.fr › spectacles › voyage-dans-la-lune
15 nov. 2016 - En s'amusant à visiter les débuts du cinéma muet, Voyage dans la Lune est un ciné-concert détonnant, qui nous plonge dans un univers de ...

Les premiers hommes dans la Lune - Editions de l'Aube
editionsdelaube.fr › catalogue_de_livres › les-premiers-hommes-dans-la-lu...
2 nov. 2017 - Roman d'anticipation dans la droite ligne de Jules Verne, Les premiers hommes dans la Lune mêle aventure, réflexions sociale et politique ...

On a trouvé des traces de Théia dans la Lune - Sciences et ...
https://www.sciencesetavenir.fr › espace › on-a-trouve-des-traces-de-theia-...
10 juin 2014 - Une nouvelle analyse confirme l'hypothèse que la Lune est née d'un impact entre la Terre et un corps de la taille de Mars, appelée Théia.

Paroles Nous, les baleines par Michèle Bernard - Paroles.net ...
https://www.paroles.net › michele-bernard › paroles-nous-les-baleines
Paroles de la chanson Nous, les baleines par Michèle Bernard. Nous, les baleines, on part dans la Lune Dans la Lune, y a pas d'eau, c'est dommage. Y a pas ...

Dans la lune - Les Docs du Nord
docsdunord.fr › films › dans-la-lune
Dans la lune est une web série humoristique de science-fiction, tendance steampunk ou retro-futuriste, inspirée de l'univers de Jules Verne et de Méliès ...